# Javascript radio button issue

Tags: javascript

Im trying to validate gender radio buttons. It works if they are not selected, but even when one is selected it still says that "gender is not selected"..does anyone know how to get around this?

I have..

```
if (!genderMaleRadioButton.checked  || !genderFemaleRadioButton.checked) {
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "Gender not selected\n";
}

//displays error messages
if (errorMessage) {
    alert(errorMessage);
}

//if all information is valid, submission is a success.
else if(!errorMessage) {    
    alert("Submission successful, thank you " + firstName.value);
}
```

Comment: Hi.  I tried reformatting your code to be more in line with conventions (which I do strongly recommend you follow, they are not just to look a certain way, they prevent some common mistakes). I didn't move the comment above the 'else if' but i would recommend you put the else if on the same line as the closing brace of the if, e.g. "} else if (!errorMessage) {"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying "if the male button is not pressed OR the female button is not pressed, then display the error message."  Change the first line to

`if(!genderMaleRadioButton.checked && !genderFemaleRadioButton.checked)`,

which makes it say "if the male button is not pressed AND the female button is not pressed, then display the error message."

Comment: Ah got it! Thank you for the replies, rookie mistake :p Makes sense now.

Comment: @Atlas182, everyone makes mistakes.  I once spent 10 minutes on a stylesheet figuring out why it wouldn't load when I noticed that I had a typo in my link tag.

Comment: haha ya i've had those days too, searching for everything but a typo. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You should use &&

```
if(!genderMaleRadioButton.checked  && !genderFemaleRadioButton.checked)
{
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "Gender not selected\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `||`, which means "or". "Or" boolean operator returns `true` when at least one of the boolean values is not equal to zero.

It would be more prudent to check if either of them are *true* just for code clarity (checking for "not nots" can be confusing when dealing with a lot of info. In your case, it doesn't matter much, but imagine a big program which is written in a way that you see the exceptions first and the expected flow always goes last?).